# Pixi js: recognize objects on image

Tags: pixi.js

I want to create carcassonne-like game using pixi js. Each tile is a separate image and I need to recognize some objects on this image like roads, towns etc. Is it possible to use pixi for this purpose? If yes what approach I need to use? I googled it but can't find anything useful.

Comment: So you are basically building a turn-based strategy game. I am actually building an engine for turn-based strategy games: ttps://github.com/Hachitus/FlaTWorld , but it is yet in pretty unstable stage and under development. You can see a test map here: https://warmapengine.level7.fi/tests/manualStressTest.html (accept the connection, since it's https and no "valid" certificate installed) just push start and see.

There are other implementations too, that can fit better for you at this stage. I recommend to at least check PIXI forums: http://www.html5gamedevs.com/forum/15-pixijs/

Comment: Also Ivan poelyshev has some tilemaps done in PIXI: https://github.com/ivanpopelyshev , those might fit better for your project.

And also you can check phaser (phaser.io), if it works better for you. Though I don't consider the normal web-engines to provide much useful stuff regarding turn-based strategy, which is why I'm implementing my own engine too.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Of course you can use pixi.js for this purpose. But you should keep in mind that pixi is not a gaming engine. It's just a renderer, so you have to do a lot of the calculations like collisions and positioning for your game by yourself.

A possible approach (I'm sure there are tons of other ways to do it):

1. You should preload all of you images
2. Create a Container: `var myContainer = new PIXI.Container();`
3. Create textures for your images: `var texture = new PIXI.Texture(yourImageStoringObject)`
4. Add the textures to you container: `myContainer.addChild(texture);`
5. Create an additional container holding your hit areas (roads, towns
   etc) and add this container to the main container again.
6. Create some pixi geometrics like rectangles (`new
   PIXI.Rectangle(x,y,w,h)`) or circles representing you hit areas and
   add them to your hit-area-container

Right now my answer is kind of a abstract approach. I'm just guessing what could help you to start your project. Try to figure out some basics and ask for help again. If you could provide some chunks of code it's a lot easier to help out! :)

Comment: "It's just a renderer," - yeah, now I use phaserjs. My 1st choice was made using this page https://html5gameengine.com/